# I cannot find module '#auth' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307) and Property 'default' does not exist on type '<P extends GithubProfile>

Tags: typescript, github, nuxt.js

```
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth'
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
export default NuxtAuthHandler({
    providers: [
        GithubProvider.default ({
            clientId: 'enter-your-client-id-here',
            clientSecret: 'enter-your-client-secret-here',
        }),
    ],
})
```

The 1st line at #auth and the 5th line at .default isn't working for some reason and I don't know why

I was working on a Nuxt Auth Project and I encounted this problem while configuring the Github credentials. I have tried a few times other things (changing import statements) but it still doesn't seem to work.